# Laravel difference between resource.create and resource.store

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I am about to learn about building RestFul apps in Laravel but I dont understand the difference between **resource.create** and **resource.store**

If I want to register and create a new user, does it then use **resource.create** or **resource.store** ?

If not, when to use **resource.create** ? And when should I use **resource.store** ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 65, accepted):

just a simple example. (*oversimplification*)

let's say you are writing a blog.

the `GET` request you are sending to get the form (where you will write the blog) is `resource.create`.

after finishing the writing, when you will submit and `POST` the content so that it gets saved in somewhere, it is `resource.store`

in your case,

`registration form` is `resource.create`.

saving the info (submitting the form) is `resource.store`.

Comment: Super simple, thanks! Then I am only going with store() since im hooking my api up to an iOS app.

Comment: Thanks this is strangely vauge in the documentation

Comment: @plushyObject Very, very vague, and not needed in most cases. It just makes everything so confusing.

Comment: I don't get it.. why would you need a create() function in backend for the form when you have <form> in front end? can you give me an example when you would want to prepare the form?

Comment: The create function displays the form. Not the other way around by convention.

Answer (score 12):

`resource.create` shows the form for creating a new resource (front end only to show the form) and `resource.store` stores a newly created resource in storage (db interaction to store the data).

Answer (score 3):

The **create** method should return a view with a form.

The **store** method should handle the form and create the entity and redirect.

The **edit** method should return a view with a form with data from the entity.

The **update** method should handle the form and update the entity and redirect.

Answer (score 2):

`resource.create` = Frontend

`resource.store` = Backend

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).